# Meaning of denseness in a $L^p$ spaces?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, definition

I am currently studyind **Density theorems in $L^p$ - spaces.** In that, I have encountered a theorem which goes like this -

The space of integrable simple functions is dense in $L^p $(E, $\mathcal{A}$ , $\mu$) where E is a measurable set, $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma -$ algebra and $\mu$ is the measure.

I have some troubles in understanding the denseness of the above given space. Does the denseness mean that union of all the simple function and their limit functions gives me the $L^p$(E, $\mathcal{A}$ , $\mu$) space ? I suppose this denseness is same as that in case of a topological space. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as a topological space. If $D$ is dense in $L^p$,
$$ \forall f \in L^p, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \phi \in D\mid \lVert f - \phi \rVert_p = \left(\int |f - \phi|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p} < \epsilon
$$
The metric is usually the $L^p$ metric unless stated otherwise.

Comment: So, my understanding of denseness in terms of union of simple functions is correct?

Comment: @Dark_Knight By union do you mean a set?

Comment: @Dark_Knight Any $L^p$ function is the limit, in the $L^p$ metric/topology, of a sequence of simple functions.

Comment: @Henry W. - Yes, the sets of values that the simple function and their limit functions take.

Comment: @Dark_Knight Then the answer is yes. You can construct a list in $D$ that approach any function in $f \in L^p$. (Taking $\epsilon = 1,1/2,1/3,1/4\dots$)

Comment: @Ian - Does this follows from the definition of denseness?

Comment: @Dark_Knight Yes, even in a general topological space.

Comment: @Dark_Knight The topology on a metric space is generated by the base of open balls, so the denseness definitions are equivalent.